# Download large Oracle table to csv file

Tags: oracle

I have a large Oracle table that I want to download into a csv file, but it is too big to load the table into memory in the one go. I want to do repeated queries to load the first 100,000 records say, then the next 100,000 and so on. My problem is ensuring that each query returns different records from before.

I use an inner query of the form shown below where A is the primary key so the order should be guaranteed.

```
SELECT  A,  B, C, rownum rn FROM my_table   ORDER BY A  asc
```

I planned to have an outer query that selected chunks of this table using a WHERE clause for a range of rn values.

The problem is that every time I run the inner query, rn is in an arbitrary order that is different from before.

What is the best way to extract the unique chunks of the table?

Comment: what's your Oracle version? and is there any primary key/unique key on your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just page the results.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY A asc
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```